# Copying data in pivot table to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, pivot

I'm stuck with my vba script where I copy data from my pivot table to Word for reporting reasons.

```
       Set TCD = wsSheet.PivotTables(1)
        TCD.TableRange2.Copy
        AppWord.Selection.Paste
```

At that time in Word I see my data in preview within Word, data & headers. I can manage size, borders, ... via VBA

BUT when I try to print (printer or PDF), copy, whatever my data are hidden and Word print only the frame of the table without ANY data!

Has anyone dealt with such a situation already?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it's possible that links to your Excel data are being pasted in Word, instead of the values. You might try pasting just the values to a temp worksheet first [Paste:=xlPasteValues](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/value-paste-pastespecial/), and then copy that range from the temp sheet to Word.

Comment: If you have some experience with a programming language outside VBA, it would be much easier to implement, maintain and probably have more freedom on the reporting by reading the excel file and generating the report. For example, you could read the excel file with python, and generate a report on whichever format you want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.